# Identical default gateway with different metric (0 and 100) Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have recently started to configure my network using `/etc/network/interfaces` for a static IP address. For this I have added the following lines into the file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.232
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

I have also changed `managed=true` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

Everything works fine so far.

Today I realized that I have two identical default gateways (via a bash default gateway failover bash script that wouldn't work because of that reason).

Route shows the following:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

The default gateway 192.168.0.1 shows up twice, once with metric 0 and once with 100. Is this the way it is supposed to be?

There are no files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` so I have no idea where that gateway is coming from. I don't have any scripts running that would add the gateway.

How do I remove one of them so it's gone permanently?

Answer (score 2):

I could solve this problem by changing `managed=false` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`